# ffmpeg: concat videos and images

Tags: ffmpeg, video-editing

I have 2 videos (same resolution, same encoding) files that I want to concat and I want to insert some text for 3 seconds between them, as a splitter. I'm doing this with ffmpeg on Windows.

Optional ideas that I would be interested in:

- avoid reencoding the video in the process
- having a fade in / fade out at the intersection of each part

For now, I made the text as an image (but I am open to other suggestions). Let's say I have:

- video1.mp4: 6:33
- splitter.png (same resolution as video1.mp4)
- video2.mp4: 16:44

I have tried a few things, but I always end up with the same problem: the video is 23:20 (video1 + 3 seconds + video2), but the 3 seconds gap is just the last video1 frame frozen instead of my image/text...

Any Idea what I did wrong or how I should achieve this?

Here is what I tried so far:

#### Method 1: image to video

Turn the image into a 3 seconds mp4 film, then concat (demuxer) it with the others:

```
ffmpeg -loop 1 -f image2 -i splitter.png -r 30 -t 3 splitter.mp4
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -codec copy output.mp4
```

Where the `input.txt` looks like:

```
file 'E:\video1.mp4'
file 'E:\splitter.mp4'
file 'E:\video2.mp4'
```

The content of `splitter.png` is visible in the `splitter.mp4`, but not in the `output.mp4`. Also I'm not entirely sure the splitter.mp4 respects the exact same encoding as the 2 videos, and I don't know how to verify that.

#### Method 2: insert image frames

Directly run the concat (demuxer) 90 times (30fps -> 3 seconds) on the image

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -codec copy output.mp4
```

Where the `input.txt` looks like:

```
file 'E:\video1.mp4'
file 'E:\splitter.png'
...
file 'E:\splitter.png'
file 'E:\video2.mp4'
```

#### Edit: possible solution?

Since all I'm doing is screencasting, I might as well screencast my splitter image. This way I would be sure of the audio & video encoding and wouldn't have any problem merging and it wouldn't need any reencoding... I know it might sound dumb, but it would probably do the trick...

Note: I didn't have try it, since I already worked through Openshot.

Comment: I solve this by forcing the pixel format: use `-pix_fmt=yuv420p` for all the input files of the concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is this is all a codec issue -- the PNG turned MP4 is probably not the same codec as your real MP4s.

Try this -- [concatenation of files of different codecs](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#differentcodec).

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. But in the example given in your link, ffmpeg expects audio stream in every video. My splitter.mp4 only have video stream. I'm not sure how to handle that...

Comment: Just an idea, but are your image videos all different lengths?  Otherwise you could always just include a wav (or other) file of silence.

Comment: Not sure what the "different lenghts" was about, but adding a silent but real stream to the splitter sounds good. I'm trying it. Doesn't seem to work, but I need to search on my own for now. I'll be back tomorrow. Thanks :)

Comment: The idea was a good one, although it didn't work in the end: I have other issues with the video stream of my splitter... Anyway, I ended installing ubuntu+openshot (yeah, I was that desperate) and it did the trick... Still, thanks for your help