# How to merge several transparent images into a single image with php

Tags: php, image

I want to merge several transparent images into a single image one above another in PHP

Input:

1 I have 5 images of the same height and width
2 each part contains part of the full image with a transparent background

Output:

A single image with the same height and width of the input images

I have not worked much with images except captcha generation,  is there a way?

Comment: U mean concatenate images??

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18452058/ffmpeg-concat-videos-and-images

Comment: @MixedVeg not exactly concatenate it wont join one after another . it need to be join one above another.

Comment: try this http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopymerge.php

Comment: and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4419383/how-can-i-merge-3-images-into-1-image-via-php

Comment: Or you coudl do it with CSS, by simply positioning them all at the same X,Y coordinates when you display them :-)

Comment: ya  @Mawg i have dun that with js for viewing now i need to save them as file ...